# Python Socket, MAC address format

Tags: python, sockets, struct

I am new to python, and trying to create a packet parser. Then I stripped off the ethernet packet from the socket from the following commands:

```
    >>raw=socket.socket(socket.PF_PACKET,socket.SOCK_RAW,socket.htons(0x800)) # Raw Packed Created
    >>raw=raw.recvfrom(2048) #Received data from socket
    >>raw

   ('\x01\x00^\x00\x00\x01T\xe6\xfc\xd0\x93\x10\x08\x00F\xc0\x00 \x00\x00@\x00\x01\x02Bm\xc0\xa8\x01\x01\xe0\x00\x00\x01\x94\x04\x00\x00\x11d\xee\x9b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00', ('eth0', 2048, 2, 1, 'T\xe6\xfc\xd0\x93\x10'))

    >> ether=raw[0][0:14] #Ethernet header

    >>ether_unpack=struct.unpack("!6s6s2s",ether) #Unpack ethernet header into string form
    >>ether_unpack #print unpacked data
    ('\x01\x00^\x00\x00\x01', 'T\xe6\xfc\xd0\x93\x10', '\x08\x00')

    >>ether_hex=binascii.hexlify(ether_unpack[0]) #converted data into hexadecimal format
    .
    .
    .
    tcpHeader=raw[0][34:54] #strippin TCP packet
    tcp_hdr=struct.unpack("!HH16s", tcpHeader) // TCP header unpack
```

First Question : what is the format of '\x01\x00^\x00\x00\x01'; What is the format of numerics in my first output

Second question: ether=raw[0][0:14]; [0:14] that takes 14 bytes from first tuple? Requires confirmation

Third Question:  `tcp_hdr=struct.unpack("!HH16s", tcpHeader)` What does the first argument do? I took this command from somewhere, and cannot figure out why the there are 'double H' in the first argument.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please give more details on the first question. I dont really understand the question

Comment: @PhucTran Added explanations!

Comment: This may help you: `The first 20 bytes of "packet" is the IP Header, and the rest is the sniffed data.` http://www.pythonforpentesting.com/2014/03/python-raw-sockets.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20800575/2382792

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The first element of `raw` is an hex format string, you can convert it to an int list using:

```
 >> payload = [int(x.encode('hex'), 16) for x in raw[0]]
 >> [1, 0, 94, 0, 0, 1, 84, 230, 252, 208, 147, 16, 8, 0, 70, 192, 0, 32, 0, 0, 64, 0, 1, 2, 66, 109, 192, 168, 1, 1, 224, 0, 0, 1, 148, 4, 0, 0, 17, 100, 238, 155, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

2) Yes, `raw[0][0:14]` takes the first 14 bytes of the first element of the `raw` tuple.

3) The first argument for the unpack function is the format in which the given string should be unpacked (https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html).  The first character of the format string can be used to indicate the byte order, size and alignment of the packed data; the `!` character in this case is for big-endian or little-endian. The 'double H' means that two unsigned short integers should be unpacked (2 bytes each), followed by a 16 characters string defined by `16s` (16 bytes), accordingly `tcpHeader` is a 20 bytes string and `tcp_hdr` stores a (int, int, string) tuple.